# Is my proof that empty set is open and R is open correct?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, elementary-set-theory

**Claim:** The empty set is open.

*Proof.* Assume that the empty set is closed. Then, there must be one point such that any point in its ball is not inside of the empty set. However, the empty set has no point at all and therefore no such point and ball exists. This is a contradiction.

**Claim:** $\mathbb{R}$ is open.

*Proof.* Assume $\mathbb{R}$ is closed. Then its complement, the empty set, is open. But, we know that the empty set is closed. This is a contradiction.

What I am worried about is that for the first proof, empty set is closed too.
So, getting contradiction while assuming that empty set is closed is little bit weird. 
and same reason goes for second proof, since it is clear that R is closed too.

Can anyone modify it please?

Comment: "Not open" does not mean "closed." In any event, $\emptyset$ is closed.

Comment: "Sets are not doors."

Answer (score 2):

'Not closed' does not mean open, for example the set $[0,1)$ is neither open nor closed. And, as you suggest, sets can be both open and closed (as both $\varnothing$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are).

You should use the definition of 'open' directly. Namely, for $X=\varnothing$ and $X=\mathbb{R}$, prove that for every $x \in X$ there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $(x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon) \subseteq X$.

Comment: "Not closed" does not mean open...these words bring back fond memories. Some awesome comic relief concerning topology: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyD4p8_y8Kw

Comment: for empty set, there is no point in it, then how could I use definition

Comment: @Clive: It is easy to prove that for every $x∈\mathbb{R}$ there exists $ε>0$ such that $(x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. But how about $X=\varnothing$, by using your definition?

Comment: It's very easy to prove that things are true for all $x\in \varnothing$.

Comment: As MJD suggests, any statement is true 'for all $x \in \varnothing$', because the statement needs to be verified in precisely no cases. This phenomenon is called [vacuous truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Comment: All points in the empty set are purple elephants, because there is no point in the set which is not a purple elephant.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{R}$ is open because if $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then for any $d > 0$, the ball centred at $x$ of radius $d$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}$ (where could it be otherwise?).

The empty set is open because if it were not, then there would be an element $x$ in the empty set for which, for any chosen $d > 0$, the ball centred at $x$ of radius $d$ is not in the empty set; but this means that there is an element in the empty set, which is impossible. (This is called a vacuous proof).

Comment: Hi, I understand why R is open. When you prove it, do you need to specifically prove why "the ball centered at x of radius d is contained in R" ?

Comment: It doesn't really need a proof, it is too obvious. But just in case you want a formal proof, you might say: Let x be in R. Let r > 0. Then: B(x,r) = {u in R such that |u - x| < r}, which means that B(x,r) is a subset of R, because for an element to be in B(x,r) it should first be in R.